# How to search for an object in List<object> having its field value

Tags: c#, oop, list, object

The question is how to get an object from List having its field value

I have got list called f_objects filled with objects.

```
private List<F_object> f_objects;
```

i've got also a string with some value :

```
string name = "something";
```

F_object got a method returning its field called name:

```
public string GetName()
{
    return this.name;
}
```

Is there a built in method for compare objects in list vs this field value ? Or should i make a loop and compare  like this:

```
foreach(F_object ob in f_objects)
{
    if String.Equals(name, ob.GetName())
    F_object found = ob;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for such fast replays !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this in linq. 
First one is to use `.Where`. This would suite your needs if there can be more matches

```
IEnumerable<F_object> result = f_objects.Where(obj=>obj.GetName() == name);
```

Second option is if you are only concerned about the first hit, even if there could be more than one, in that case use `.First`

```
f_object result = f_objects.First(obj=>obj.GetName() == name);
```

or if zero hits is an accepted situation (non-exceptional)

```
f_object result = f_objects.FirstOrDefault(Obj=>obj.GetName() == name);
```

if you should only ever have one hit then use `.Single`

```
f_object result = f_objects.Single(obj=>obj.GetName() == name);
```

or if you can have only one or zero hits then use `.SingleOrDefault`

```
f_object result = f_objects.SingleOrDefault(obj=>obj.GetName() == name);
```

Comment: .First/.Single are good points to remember, I tend to forget they exist. I posted an answer in here but I've given you a vote for including those.

Answer (score 8):

Using LINQ:

```
List<F_object> found = f_objects.Where(obj => obj.GetName() == name).ToList();
```

That's a list of all the matching objects.

**Edit:** Rune FS' answer also has good advice for using `.Single()` or `.First()` instead of `.Where()` if you expect or only care about grabbing one distinct value.

Comment: Your solution will help me in future when i need to search for multiple match. For now i need to select one object(because name is unique) so Alex's solutions best suits me. Thanks for helping !

Comment: @Alan Alex solution won't give you one item it will give you an IEnumerabl<bool> where the value will idicate where or not the names matched for that particular object in f_objects

Comment: @Rune FS: I don't know how it would return a IEnumerable<bool>, if I put my solution into the compiler, the result set is of IEnumerable<F_Object>.

Comment: @Alex since you've changed the code yourself from one that did return an IEnumerable<bool> to one that returns an IEnumerable<F_Object> after I posted the comment I'm pretty sure you know what I refferred to :)

Comment: Its all good :) - as Chris noticed, you guys were commenting it as if it wasn't updated. That got me confused.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<...> items = ... ;
string name = ...;
var found = items.Find( i => string.Equals(name, i.GetName()) );
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use LINQ.

```
var objectswith_something = f_objects.Where(fo => fo.GetName().Equals(name));
```

If you just want the first, use

```
f_objects.Where(fo => fo.GetName().Equals(name)).FirstOrDefault();`
```

Comment: This solution best suits me because there is only one object with specified name.

Comment: What does `fo.GetName().Equals(name)` return? an object or a bool? Your answer return bool array( or a single bool)

Comment: that returns a list of booleans false if the fields are different and true if they are equal. It _doesn't_ filter which OP is looking for

Comment: The Where requires a Func<T,bool> - using Equals returns a bool.

Comment: This does return an `IEnumerable<F_object>`. `fo.GetName().Equals(name)` is exactly the same as `fo.GetName() == name`, and behaves as you would expect. It would only return an `IEnumberable<bool>` if you used the `.Select()` call instead of `.Where()`.

Comment: I think you guys are talking about 2 different things. Equals() returns a bool, Where (Which requires a Func<T,bool> returns a IEnumerable<T>. ...

Comment: @ChrisWalsh.  It was `Select` before update. See edits. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8249018/revisions

Comment: Yes I know, I noticed that it was a mistake so I changed it.

Comment: @L.B I am aware, but people were commenting as if it had not been updated much later after it had been modified.

Answer (score 3):

There are still people that cannot use LINQ in theirs projects, so here is version without it:

```cs
F_object found = f_objects.Find(delegate(F_object f)
{
    return f.GetName().Equals(name);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

the best way is to search using the Linq Expressions assuming you are using 3.5 or above.

For example you would write

```
IEnumerable<F_object> filteredListOff_objects f_objects.Where(f_object=>f_object.GetName() == "something");
```

To get an IEnumberable of the objects that have the name "something"

Answer (score 0):

Another version using the Query Syntax. I think this is more readable than the code with the lambda expressions. In the end, it will be the same.

```
string name = "something";
var foundQuery = from s in f_objects
                 where s.Name == name
                 select s;
```

I would declare a property Name instead of GetName().
Then you can iterate with foreach over the query:

```
foreach (string s in foundQuery)
   ...
```

or convert it to a List<> or an Array with ToList or ToArray.