# Flutter: How to search a 'set' for an object based on the object's field value

Tags: flutter, dart, set, contains

As per the title how do I search a 'Set' for an object by the objects field value. The following is incorrect code but hopefully gives the idea. The closest i could find was [How to search for an object in List<object> having its field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249002/how-to-search-for-an-object-in-listobject-having-its-field-value) but the same doesn't seem to apply.

```
class MyClass {
  final String a;
  final int b;
  final double c;
  MyClass({this.a, this.b, this.c});
}

class Check{
   Set<MyClass> mSet = new Set<MyClass>();
   contains() {
     mSet.add(new MyClass(a: "someString1", b:3, c:2.0));
     mSet.add(new MyClass(a: "someString2", b:1, c:3.0));
     mSet.add(new MyClass(a: "someString3", b:2, c:1.0));
     //following is not correct, but to get the idea...
     print(mSet.contains((item) => item.a == "someString1"));
     //need to return true
   }
}

>FALSE
```

Same question might apply to Set.where,  Set.remove ...etc for instance if I add

```
var b = mSet.where((item) => item.a == "someString1");
```

b results in an iterable with **all** values of the Set.

Answer (score 1):

In dart, Set extends Iterable. [There are lots of useful methods that you can call on an iterable that effectively sort the iterable according to some value](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/Iterable-class.html).

For example, you can say:

```
void main() {

  Check().contains();

}


class MyClass {
  final String a;
  final int b;
  final double c;
  MyClass({this.a, this.b, this.c});

  @override
  String toString(){
    return a;
  }
}

class Check{
   Set<MyClass> mSet = new Set<MyClass>();
   contains() {
     mSet.add(new MyClass(a: "someString1", b:3, c:2.0));
     mSet.add(new MyClass(a: "someString2", b:1, c:3.0));
     mSet.add(new MyClass(a: "someString3", b:2, c:1.0));

     print(mSet.firstWhere((item) => item.a == "someString1"));

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kris, so really it's just that "contains" doesn't include a conditional option. I might delete this post given it is a simple overlook on my behalf. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To summarise then following Kris' comments, to return a bool from a query of an object's  field, '***contains***' cannot be used. Instead you could use ***where*** or maybe other methods from the ***Set*** class that adopt a test element eg
`(bool test(E element), { E orElse() }) → E)` (https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/Set-class.html),
and add a ternary operator to return the desired bool result.

```
void main() {
  print(Check().contains());
}

class MyClass {
  final String a;
  final int b;
  final double c;
  MyClass({this.a, this.b, this.c});
}

class Check{
   Set<MyClass> mSet = new Set<MyClass>();
   bool contains() {
     mSet.add(new MyClass(a: "someString1", b:3, c:2.0));
     mSet.add(new MyClass(a: "someString2", b:1, c:3.0));
     mSet.add(new MyClass(a: "someString3", b:2, c:1.0));
     return mSet.where((item) => item.a  == "someString1").length > 0;
   }
}

>>true
```

**EDIT**: after trying a few other 'test element' methods (eg ***firstWhere*** and ***lastWhere***) it seems '***where***' is the only method I've tested that doesn't fail if there is no match. If you use the others you need a catch then to return false. I've stuck with '***where***' and a ternary for the cleanest solution as per the revised code above. If only '***contains***' included a test element.